# Translate module in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I want translate module from english to russian.

1. I'm install Russian language and export mymodule.po file for my module (Administration ‣ Translations -> Import/Export ‣ Export Translation)
2. Create i18n directory and add file ru.po
3. In ru.po file add all line from mymodule.po file (from step 1 and and translate the missing terms).
4. Synchronize all (Administration ‣ Translations ‣ Application Terms ‣ Synchronize Translations)

After login (User with russian language) any changes not visible...only english.

Where is problem?

Comment: Have you tried to reload the browsers tab with new cache? (chrome SHIFT + F5)

Comment: @CZoellner yes after clear cache and  Synchronize terms, work fine...ps. add your answer below....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activate developper mode then load the translation again and click on override existing terms, then make sure that you  changed the prefference of the user lang to Russian no need to logout because after saving the page will reload automaticly  and you will see the translation if it's not the case than your translations is not loaded correctly. if you po file is in the model and in the directory i18n than wen you load the tranlation again it's should appear if not try upgrade than load keep trying.